# UIScrollView is put beneath UITableViewCellContentView making it unresponsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, tableview

So I'm trying to add a scrollview to a tableview cell, I use XIBs and autolayout. Everything is correctly setup but I have this one problem that I don't really understand.

The problem is that the scrollview is not added to the uitebleview cell content view, it is added below.

Here is the structure and as you can see the contentview uiview is above the scrollview, eating the touches.

[image: Imgur]

The current solution is that I do `[self bringSubviewToFront:self.scrollView]` to force the scrollview to be the top view. But this feels a bit like a hacky solution.

Comment: Why don't you put the scroll view in the content view?

Comment: @AaronBrager This is the view in IB, http://snappy-app.com/YteGcq am I doing something wrong here? I've never experienced this problem before.

Comment: Yeah. You should have a view called `contentView` and the scroll view should be inside of that.

Comment: Hm, would I just manually add it and name it "contentView" then? As nothing is present like that here: http://snappy-app.com/uBWdqz

Comment: @AaronBrager Got it, I had the base view in the XIB file as a normal UIView (and only the "class" as my custom tableviewcell class). I dragged a uitableviewcell into the view and copied all items into that views uitableviewcells content view now! Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment chain above on the question:

> Got it, I had the base view in the XIB file as a normal UIView (and only the "class" as my custom tableviewcell class). I dragged a uitableviewcell into the view and copied all items into that views uitableviewcells content view now! Thanks!